# Using Auth::user() in Laravel ComposerSeriveProvider

Tags: php, laravel

I have a sidebar, where I want to display logged in user's favorite topics.

I'm using **ComposerServiceProvider** to set user's data in the view:

```
public function boot(UserRepository $userRepository)
{
    if(Auth::check()) {
        view()->composer('common.sidebar', function ($view) use($userRepository) {
            $view->with('topics', $userRepository->getRecentFollowingTopics(Auth::user()));
        });
    }
}
```

But as the documentation says, this will loaded before other services, like **Auth**, so `Auth::check()` not working here. As they also wrote about this:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7600

How can I achieve to use *ViewComposers* with checking the user authentication? Also any other suggestion appriciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your boot function `Auth` is not yet available, that's correct.

However, in your closure it is! So just refactor your code to this:

```
// Notice the dependency injection of the Guard! Don't forget to import it on top of your Service Provider
public function boot(Guard $auth, UserRepository $userRepository)
{
    view()->composer('common.sidebar', function ($view) use($auth, $userRepository) {
        if($auth->check()) {
            $view->with('topics', $userRepository->getRecentFollowingTopics($auth->user()));
        }
    });
}
```

In this case I would also probably refactor your `getRecentFollowingTopics` function to return `null` if `$auth->user()` should be `null` (which it is, if no user is logged in) and just check for `isNull($topics)` in your template.

Also, did you know that in Laravel 5 you can inject classes directly into blade like this:

```
@inject('userRepository', 'App\UserRepository')
```

and then use it, for example, like this:

```
@if(!is_null($topics = $userRepository->getRecentFollowingTopics(auth()->user())))
    @foreach ($topics as $topic)
    ....
    @endforeach
@else
    show whatever you like
@endif
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Also didn't know about the `@inject` :)